# Textbook on Differentiation

Tags: derivatives, book-recommendation

I recently came across a book entirely devoted to different types of integrals called [*A Garden of Integrals*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088385337X) by Frank Burk.  I'm reading through it and it's a pretty good book.  Is there some analogous book for different types of derivatives?  For example, it might cover: the weak derivative, subderivatives, gradients, Jacobians, Frechet derivatives, Gateaux derivaties, functional derivatives, fractional derivatives, exterior derivatives, Lie derivatives, etc.

I can see why it might be easier to make a book about different types of integrals than different types of derivatives, but I'm still curious if there is such a book.  Has anyone come across one?

Comment: Never seen such a book...

Comment: Not really, because derivatives are much, much simpler. Here's integrals: http://i.imgur.com/11hGmBW.png

Comment: @mistermarko calculation techniques/strategies have nothing to do with what OP is asking. "A Garden of Integrals" is sort of a historic overview of the concept examining the various things that have been called integrals.

Comment: Well, the answer is definitely 'no' then because 'derivative' in mathematics only has one meaning (that within calculus). To clarify, the integrals in the flow chart linked above are the calculus integrals.